# How do I get past the rotating red bridge room?

Tags: subway-midnight

There is a rotating red room where turning parts of the room makes bridges appear and disappear. I've tried rotating for a while, but I can't figure out how to solve the puzzle.

How do I get past the rotating red bridge room?

[image: Red rotating room]